# How can I update json data in MySQL with Laravel framework?

Tags: php, mysql, json, database, laravel

I want to create a ticketing system with Laravel. I store the chat data's in json data type. when user want to send her/his ticket i get her/his data and store its with these code:

```php
$messages = array([
    'message_title' => post('message_title'),
    'message_body' => post('message_body'),
    'type' => 'q',
    'created_at' => date('Y/m/d H:i:s'),
]);

$messagesToJson = json_encode($messages);
$query = DB::table('test')->insert([
    'level_id' => post('message_level'),
    'status' => 0,
    'ticket_id' => post('user_id') . time(),
    'user_id' => post('user_id'),
    'backend_user_id' => '',
    'messages' => $messagesToJson,
]);
```

these data store in MySQL:

```
[
    {"message_title":"This is title","message_body":"Some text ... .","type":"q","created_at":"2020\/02\/29 20:42:26"}
]
```

But my problem is: when the user want ask a new question in this ticket how can i insert a new object in this array like this:

```
[
    {"message_title":"This is title","message_body":"Some text ... .","type":"q","created_at":"2020\/02\/29 20:42:26"},
    {"message_title":"Question 2","message_body":"Some text in question 2 ... .","type":"q","created_at":"2020\/02\/29 21:42:26"}
]
```

My update code is:

```php
$messages = array(
    'message_body' => post('sendText'),
    'type' => 'q',
    'created_at' => date('Y/m/d H:i:s'),
);

$messagesToJson = json_encode($messages);
$updateQuery = DB::update("UPDATE synon_subsystem_ticketing
                  SET messages = JSON_SET(messages, '$[$countMessages]', '$messagesToJson') WHERE id = '$id'");
```

Comment: please post your current update function.

Comment: Add update code in my question.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 options:

1. Get current value, append your message and update:

   ```php
   $tiket = DB::table('synon_subsystem_ticketing')->find($id);

   $messages = json_decode($ticket->messages) ?? []; //json_decode is not necessary if you're using attribute casting on your model
   $messages[] = array(
       'message_body' => post('sendText'),
       'type' => 'q',
       'created_at' => date('Y/m/d H:i:s'),
   );
   $messages = json_encode($messages); //json_encode is not necessary if you're using attribute casting on your model

   DB::table('synon_subsystem_ticketing')
       ->where('id', $id)
       ->update(['messages' => $messages]);
   ```

   Note: Check Laravel docs on [json column on migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#column-modifiers) and [updating json column](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#updating-json-columns)
2. Use MySql [`JSON_ARRAY_APPEND`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-array-append) function on a raw query.

Comment: Dear Hafez, i used the 1 way, but i get this error: [] operator not supported for strings, this error point to $messages[] = ...

Comment: @FarzinBidokhti seem you need to `json_decode` your messages, check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL supports json columns. You can create and update json columns in laravel as shown below.

```
$table->json('tickets_user_info'); // in your migration create json column.

//Update it as shown below.
$affected = DB::table('users')
          ->where('id', 1)
          ->update(['tickets_user_info' => 'what_ever_you_want_to_save_here']);
```

You can create new array including old data and update your json column with all data.

Read laravel's [Query Json Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#json-where-clauses) and [Updating JSON Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#updating-json-columns) also